# which technology need to be learn for creating chat app in react native

Tags: react-native, sockets, graphql

I want to create a real time. chat app in react native like watsapp or facebook , then which technology to be used .Since there are many technologies available like socket, graphql , mqtt or any other technology

Comment: Well the most important one is that you have to know fundamental structure of sockets and how to work with them. There are a lot of libraries to work with sockets. You can make a search and do tutorials with socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

- React Native uses the same fundamental UI building blocks as regular
  iOS and Android apps. You just put those building blocks together
  using JavaScript and React.
- you have to know fundamental structure of sockets Socket.io is a widely-used JavaScript library mostly used for realtime web applications. It enables real-time, two-way and event-based communication between the client (browser) and the server. It is built from Node. js and JavaScript client library.
- You should be familiar with programming concepts like functions,
  objects, arrays, and to a lesser extent, classes.
- You should have a basic knowledge of JavaScript.
- You should have some familiarity with HTML and CSS.